Xpath: Extract text between tags, but stop as soon as an embedded tag occurs
I would like to extract the text within the following HTML. However, everything that occurs within an enclosed HTML tag and everything that comes after it should be ignored.
The HTML appears in different forms.
<span class="classA">Text 1 <span class="classB">Text 2</span> Text 3 <span class="classC">Text 4</span> Text 5</span>

Desired result: "Text 1 Text 2 Text 3"
Other variants:
<span class="classA">Text 1 <span class="classC">Text 2</span></span>
<span class="classA">Text 1 <span class="classC">Text 2</span> Text 3</span>
<span class="classA">Text 1</span>

Desired result: "Text 1"
<span class="classA">Text 1 <span class="classB">Text 2</span> Text 3</span>

Desired result: "Text 1 Text 2 Text3"
So everything after the occurrence of a span element with class "classC" should be ignored. It's also possible that "classC" doesn't appear at all.
I already tried //span[@class="classA"]//text()[parent::*[not(@class="classC")]], this ignores "classC" content, but returns the text after <span class="classC"> (Text 5 from the first example).
How can I achieve this?
Update:
With //span[@class="classC"]//parent::*/preceding::text() I'm getting a little closer to the matter. However, it still doesn't work with <span class="classA">Text 1</span>, which returns noting.

Try this XPath:
//text()[not(preceding::span[@class="classC"]|ancestor::span[@class="classC"])]

but as Michael Kay said it could be very inefficient, depending on your source html.

Thanks. This works very well and seems to me to be a more efficient implementation compared to @Michael Kay's solution due to the PHP limitation on XPath v1.

This is assuming that the example <span> fragment shown in the question is the entire document to which the XPath is being applied.

@MichaelKay: correct

You haven't said which XPath version you are using. This is quite hard to achieve using XPath 1.0 which is all that PHP's DOMXPath supports.
Logically you can do
.//text() except .//span[@class="ClassC"]/following::text()

but the except operator requires XPath 2.0. A workaround is that in XPath 1.0 you can rewrite (A except B) as A[count(.|B)!=count(B)] but it's potentially very inefficient.

Thanks. This works, but I had to add //span[@class="SURN"]/text() to exclude the "Text 5" part. But compared to @siebe-jongebloed, this solution seems more complicated since PHP unfortunately doesn't support XPath v2.
